# What is this four-engine propeller airplane?

Tags: propeller, aircraft-identification, multi-engine

[image: unknown plane]

I came across this print at a bargain store a couple weeks ago. At first I thought it might be a variant of a Lockheed L-188 Electra; then I noticed that it has at least 6 engines, as the print extends around the edge of the canvas and you can see a couple of propeller tips there. I haven't had any luck finding a 6- or 8-engine aircraft that matches it.

[image]

**Edit:** after looking at it a little closer, I think the edge might be a printing effect, an imprecise mirroring around the edge line (for example, some of the splotches look very similar to those in the front). So maybe it is only four engines?

Comment: The extra engines are photoshopped mirroring to disguise the frame-less edge -- the effect is jarring when used with what is already a simple symmetric image.

Comment: @amI: You should make this an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe it's an [Ilyushin Il-18](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilyushin_Il-18). Pic from [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:IL-18_Pyongyang_to_Samjiyon.jpg):

[image: IL-18]

Comment: That's it!  Well done.  I thought it was a Brit where the artist had taken some liberties with his reproduction.